# `[.` method for `ReferenceClass`

Tags: r, methods, eval, r-s4, reference-class

I would like to write a `[.` method for my `ReferenceClass`. So far, I have something like this:

```
DT <- data.table(Index=1:5)

MySeries <- setRefClass("MySeries", fields = list(data="data.table"))

setMethod("[","MySeries",function(x, i,j,drop) {
  ii <- substitute(i)
  x$data <- x$data[eval(ii)]
  return(x)
})

S <- MySeries(data=DT)
```

... but it throws an error when I finally call `S[Index>3]`. How to fix the above to get this expected result?

```
  Index
4:  4
5:  5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really about the use of `eval(substitute())` as much as about S4 methods. Here is the generic that you are interested in

```
> getGeneric("[")
standardGeneric for "[" defined from package "base"

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE)
standardGeneric("[", .Primitive("["))
<bytecode: 0x42f4fe0>
<environment: 0x3214270>
Methods may be defined for arguments: x, i, j, drop
Use  showMethods("[")  for currently available ones.
```

Your method signature differs from the generic (no '...' and no default for 'drop') so the method has a nested '.local' function

```
> getMethod("[", "MySeries")
Method Definition:

function (x, i, j, ..., drop = TRUE) 
{
    .local <- function (x, i, j, drop) 
    {
        ii <- substitute(i)
        x$data <- x$data[eval(ii)]
        return(x)
    }
    .local(x, i, j, ..., drop)
}

Signatures:
        x         
target  "MySeries"
defined "MySeries"
```

and `subsitute(i)` is not what you think it is.  Instead, write a method matching the generic signature

```
setMethod("[", "MySeries", function(x, i, j, ..., drop=TRUE) {
    x$data <- x$data[eval(substitute(i))]
    x
})
```

nested functions are a general problem with the eval(substitute()) paradigm, not just definition of S4 methods; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) question.

Comment: wow, what a subtle error, when I quickly typed my signature `function(x,i,j,drop)`. Thanks for the insight regarding `.local`